# scrollable image gallery loop to work as after last image it should again start with first image

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a scroll-able image gallery using javascript so i am able to create it but now i want it to work like an infinite loop i.e as soon as it reaches last image then on next click it should start with first image again

that's my html code

```js
var width = 130; // image width
var count = 4; // visible images count
var list = carousel.querySelector('ul');
var listElems = carousel.querySelectorAll('li');
var position = 0;

// shift left
document.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function() {
  position += width * count;
  position = Math.min(position, 0);
  list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
};

// shift right
document.querySelector('.next').onclick = function() {
  position -= width * count;
  position = Math.max(position, -width * (listElems.length - count));
  list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
};
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 508px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
}

.arrow:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  left: 7px;
}

.next {
  right: 7px;
}

.gallery {
  width: 530px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery ul {
  height: 130px;
  width: 10000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: margin-left 350ms;
  font-size: 0;
}

.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel" id="carousel">
  <button class="arrow prev">⇦</button>
  <div class="gallery">
    <ul class="images">
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/2.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/3.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/4.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/6.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/7.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/8.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/9.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/10.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/8.png"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="arrow next">⇨</button>
</div>
```

it works fine like on clicking buttons images are srcolling but i want it to be scrollable in infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by checking, before assigning the `position`'s variable to the `style.marginLeft` :

- for the `next` button, the `position` variable equals to `-((the number of the carousel elements - four (as 4 cards should be shown)) multiplied by the width of an element)` typically `-((listElems.length - 4) * width)` then assign `0` to `position` so the carousel starts over.
- for the `prev` button, the `position` variable equals to `0` then assign to it `-((the number of the carousel elements - four (as 4 cards should be shown)) multiplied by the width of an element)`.

Here's a demo :

```js
var width = 130; // image width
var count = 4; // visible images count
var list = carousel.querySelector('ul');
var listElems = carousel.querySelectorAll('li');
var position = 0;

// shift left
document.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function() {
  position += width * count;
  position = Math.min(position, 0);
  /** check if we have to loop back from the end **/
  position === 0 && (position = -((listElems.length - 4) * width));
  list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
};

// shift right
document.querySelector('.next').onclick = function() {
  position -= width * count;
  position = Math.max(position, -width * (listElems.length - count));
  /** check if we have to loop back from the begining **/
  position === -((listElems.length - 4) * width) && (position = 0);
  list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
};
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 508px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
}

.arrow:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  left: 7px;
}

.next {
  right: 7px;
}

.gallery {
  width: 530px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery ul {
  height: 130px;
  width: 10000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: margin-left 350ms;
  font-size: 0;
}

.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel" id="carousel">
  <button class="arrow prev">⇦</button>
  <div class="gallery">
    <ul class="images">
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/2.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/3.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/4.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/6.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/7.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/8.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/9.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/10.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
      <li><img src="https://en.js.cx/carousel/8.png"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="arrow next">⇨</button>
</div>
```